# Anti Forgery Cookie Token has different ID

Tags: ajax, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, csrf

I am developing an ASP.NET Core Web Application using a combination of MVC Views and Web APIs. I also use Identity for user management.

I now want to enable Anti-Request-Forgery Tokens for our Web API. For that, I use the `IAntiForgery` service in Razor views to `GetAndStoreTokens` and forward the `RequestToken` to a `$.ajax` call as a header, as described in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery) in section JavaScript.

When I run the corresponding page that performs a Web API request with the user being signed in (Cookie-Authentication), I can also see that the request token is set properly as an HTTP Header (see orange box in image). However, the Anti-Forgery validation of ASP.NET Core denies the request with the following message:

**Antiforgery token validation failed. The required antiforgery cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ybHEizTXFmU" is not present.**

Thus, the cookie-part of the Anti-Forgery-Token (blue box) is the problem here - the key starts with a different ID: **.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.lUjKpn5xN20** instead of **.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ybHEizTXFmU**

[image: Request Headers]

**How can this happen?** The Web App and Web API reside in the same process / at the same domain, so no Cross-Origin-Calls are performed. Is this a problem of `$.ajax` (which I can't explain because the browsers cookies of the target site should be reused) or a problem within the ASP.NET Core Anti-Forgery (or even Identity) module?

Comment: Different DPAPI configurations

Comment: @Mardoxx Can you elaborate? How can the Windows Data Protection API influence the browser cookie? In the test scenario, browser as well as server run on the same machine. I'd suggest that either $.ajax picks up the wrong cookie or AntiForgery computes a false Cookie name.

Comment: Anti forgery cookies are encrypted with a key generated on startup. If you're generating them on your front end application and verifying them on your webapi application it will fail if they don't use the same key set.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, WebAPI and frontend application currently run in the same ASP.NET Core process, so this should not be the cause of the problem.